# Insert HTML table row with JavaScript with different variable names

Tags: javascript

I have a page that allows users to edit their data (On the database). I have a JavaScript that inserts rows. Those rows contain textboxes whose values are stored in different variables. So, i need a way to insert a table row that has the same structure, but different variable names.

In order to insert/edit data at the same time, i need different values on different fields. (The insertion/editing is made on the edited.php page)

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function addRow(tableID) {

        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

        var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

        for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {

            var newcell = row.insertCell(i);

            newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;
            //alert(newcell.childNodes);
            switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
                case "text":
                        newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
                        break;
                case "checkbox":
                        newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
                        break;
                case "select-one":
                        newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
                        break;
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

This Script inserts a table row on my html table. That insertion is made by copying the first table row. I need a NEW row with NEW variables.

Is there anyway to define the row that is inserted?

Comment: Does it succeed in inserting a new row?  What values did you want to insert in to the cells?

Comment: The cells contain textboxes. Those textboxes have selected information from the database, so the user just edits whatever he wants. Now i have a button that allows me to insert MORE cells with the same textboxes, but different Variables. It suceeds in inserting a new HTML row.

Comment: Can you create a http://jsfiddle.net with complete code?

Comment: I am still unclear of what exactly you want the function to do.

Comment: I want to function to insert the new table row, but with different variables. Let's say the table row has 3 textboxes, each textbox has a variable attributed ($input1, $input2, $input3). I want to create a new row with different variables. ($newinput1, $newinput2, $newimput3)

Comment: Can you please explain what you understand by **variables**?

Comment: Or at least add html structure of table element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the javascript createElement function, here is a little example that should get you on your way:

```
    function addNewRow(tableID) {

        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

        var row = document.createElement('tr');
        var data = document.createElement('td');
        var tbx = document.createElement('input');
        tbx.setAttribute('type', 'text');

        data.appendChild(tbx);

        row.appendChild(data);
        table.appendChild(row);

    }
```

it should be fairly self-explanatory, create an element, set its attributes, and add children elements to it, in your case: textbox, checkbox etc.

If you need to have dynamic ids and/or values, add a counter variable and increment as you go along and/or add parameters like

```
function addNewRow(tableID, input1, input2, input3){}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the name to each row you create dynamically like this:

```
var row_counter=0 // have a global counter
var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
row.setAttribute("id", "row"+row_counter);
//NOW INCREMENT THE COUNTER BASED ON YOUR LOOP
```

You can work out the loop in a way you want.